# QGIS and Intel Tablet Processor Compatibility

Tags: qgis, windows, tablet, compatibility

Will any Windows based tablet with an intel processor be able to run QGIS, provided it meets the requirements, or is it only the Surface Pro that is capable? Looking for a cheaper solution to the pro.

Comment: I don't have an answer for you, but there are two related questions that may provide insight or even answer the question (the first is using QGIS on a Dell tablet): http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/78857/ and http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68461/

Comment: Actually the answer to http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/68461/does-qgis-run-on-windows-surface-with-win-rt-os sparked my question. I am looking for more information on determining which tablet processors will work with QGIS. I don't want to buy an 800$ Surface for testing because if the testing has poor results I just wasted 800$.

Answer (score 1):

Found this out a while ago and forgot I asked it on here. So far I found that there are 2 types of Windows OS's Windows RT and Windows 10. If the tablet is running Windows 10 many report good operation and functionality. However, if it is running Windows RT you won't be able to install QGIS onto it. It is likely that any tablet running Windows 10 will handle QGIS.